# How does SpaCy keeps track of character and token offset during tokenization?

Tags: python, algorithm, nlp, cython, spacy

**How does SpaCy keeps track of character and token offset during tokenization?**

In SpaCy, there's a Span object that keeps the start and end offset of the token/span https://spacy.io/api/span#init

There's a [`_recalculate_indices`](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/72889a16d558848191e51f4bfb200e70d3bc413a/spacy/tokens/span.pyx#L312) method seems to be retrieving the `token_by_start` and `token_by_end` but that looks like all the recalcuation is doing.

When looking at extraneous spaces, it's doing some [smart alignment of the spans](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/72889a16d558848191e51f4bfb200e70d3bc413a/spacy/tokenizer.pyx#L95).

Does it recalculate after every regex execution, does it keep track of the character's movement? Does it do a post regexes execution span search?

Answer (score 5):

**Summary:**
During tokenization, [this](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/fa94f836979516abea5743c0be2715c14c5ebb47/spacy/tokenizer.pyx#L101) is the part that keeps track of offset and character.

Simple answer: It goes character by character in the string.

TL;DR is at the bottom.

---

**Explained chunk by chunk:**

It takes in the string to be tokenized and starts iterating through it one letter/space at a time.

It is a simple `for` loop on the string where `uc` is the current character in the string.

```py
for uc in string:
```

It first checks to see if the current character is a space and compares that to see if the last `in_ws` setting is opposite of whether it is a space or not. If they are the same, it will jump down and increase `i += 1`.

`in_ws` is being used to know if it should process or not. They want to do things on spaces as well as on characters, so they can't just track `isspace()` and operate only on `False`.  Instead, when it first starts, `in_ws` is set to the result of `string[0].isspace()` and then compared against itself.  If `string[0]` is a space, it will evaluate the same and therefor skip down and increase `i` (discussed later) and go to the next `uc` until it reaches a `uc` that is not the same as the first one. In practice this allows it to sequence through multiple spaces after having treated the first space, or multiple characters until it reaches the next space boundary.

```py
    if uc.isspace() != in_ws:
```

It will continue to go through characters until it reaches the next boundary, keeping the index of the current character as `i`.

It tracks two index values: `start` and `i`.  `start` is the start of the potential token that it is on, and `i` is the ending character it is looking at. When the script starts, `start` will be `0`. After a cycle of this, `start` will be the index of the last space plus 1 which would make it the first letter of the current word.

It checks first if `start` is less than `i` which is used to know if it should attempt to check the cache and tokenize the current character sequence. This will make sense further down.

```py
        if start < i:
```

`span` is the word that is currently being looked at for tokenization.  It is the string sliced by the `start` index value through the `i` index value.

```py
            span = string[start:i]
```

It is then taking the hash of the word (`start` through `i`) and checking the cache dictionary to see if that word has been processed already.  If it has not it will call the `_tokenize` method on that portion of the string.

```py
            key = hash_string(span)
            cache_hit = self._try_cache(key, doc)
            if not cache_hit:
                self._tokenize(doc, span, key)
```

Next it checks to see if the current character `uc` is an exact space.  If it is, it resets start to be `i + 1` where `i` is the index of the current character.

```py
        if uc == ' ':
            doc.c[doc.length - 1].spacy = True
            start = i + 1
```

If the character is not a space, it sets start to be the current character's index. It then reverses `in_ws`, indicating it is a character.

```py
        else:
            start = i
        in_ws = not in_ws
```

And then it increases `i += 1` and loops to the next character.

```py
    i += 1
```

---

**TL;DR**
So all of that said, it keeps track of the character in the string that it is on using `i` and it keeps the start of the word using `start`.  `start` is reset to the current character at the end of processing for a word, and then after the spaces it is set to the last space plus one (the start of the next word).